# How to use a SSAS fact table as a dimension

Tags: sql, ssas, cube

I am a beginner at ssas cubes:

I am busy designing a cube and would like to know if you could use a fact table as a dimension. For example say I have a fact table that has an ID column which is unique, and an Age column that has customer ages in it. Can I make a dimension where the ID is the unique column and the age is the column that is shown. When I try set the KeyColumn of the dimension to ID and the NameColumn to Age, I get all the ages of the different customers instead of the distinct ages.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can be done by leaving the KeyColumn as Age and simply making an attribute relationship between ID and Age.

Comment: Yes you are on the right track.  This is the pattern for a very flexible dimension, but it can blow up at extreme volumes.

Comment: Yes it does seem it would not work well performance wise if there is too much data. I will make a small dimension table with the ages.

Comment: You might be surprised how far it does go.  I've gotten close to 10m rows in the dimension without any major issues.  Hide the ID attribute.

Comment: Interesting, at the moment mine only has just over a million rows, but I am worried on the processing time of the cube if I don't make the separate dimension table.

Comment: Its worth giving it a go.